# Rendering options with parameters in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

This should be simple but I've been stuck for about 3 hours on it, and can't seem to find a solution. I'm new to backbone so maybe I'm overlooking something.

I'm trying to render a view where the options all have values.  It's coming out like this:

```
<select name="role" id="option-roles" class="form-control">
<option>All</option>
<option>Basic User</option>
<option>Basic Student</option>
...
</select>
```

But I want each option to have a value to look like this:

```
<option value='10'>Basic User</option>
```

In backbone my code looks like this.

```
  app.RoleSelectView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#roles',
    template: _.template($('#tmpl-roles').html()),
    initialize: function() {
      this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(app.mainView.results.roles, {
        model: app.Role
      });
      this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template());

      var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
      var view = new app.RoleOptionsView({
        model: new app.Role(),
        value: ''
      });
      frag.appendChild(view.render().el);
      this.collection.each(function(role) {
        var view = new app.RoleOptionsView({
          model: role,
          value: role.id.toString()
        });
        frag.appendChild(view.render().el);
      }, this);
      $('#option-roles').append(frag);
      return this;
    }
  });

  app.RoleOptionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'option',
    template: _.template($('#tmpl-role-option').html()),
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
      return this;
    }
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

> **el** `view.el`
>   [...]
>   `this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element; otherwise it will be created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties.

If you want to add an attribute (such as `value`) to your `el` then use `attributes`:

```
app.RoleOptionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'option',
  attributes: function() { // <---------------------------------
    return {
      value: 'where ever your value comes from'
    };
  },
  template: _.template($('#tmpl-role-option').html()),
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    return this;
  }
});
```

Also, it is generally preferred that you say `this.model.toJSON()` rather than directly accessing `this.model.attributes`.

Like most data-ish things in views, the `attributes` can either be a static object or a function which returns an object. In your case, the attributes presumably depend on something in the view's model so a function is needed so that you can work with the view instance and its model.